# Write an equation of the line tangent to the graph of $y = e^x \cos \sqrt x$ at (0,1).

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I understand and I know the procedure to get the solution, as:

$y = e^x\cos\sqrt x$

$\frac{dy}{dx}= e^x\cos\sqrt x-\frac{e^x\sin\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}$  and since $x=0$

this part $\frac{e^x\sin\sqrt x}{2\sqrt x}$ becomes undefined.
 How do I handle such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

the first derivative is given by $$f'(x)={{\rm e}^{x}}\cos \left( \sqrt {x} \right) -1/2\,{\frac {{{\rm e}^{x}}
\sin \left( \sqrt {x} \right) }{\sqrt {x}}}
$$ and if we compute $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$$ we get $$\frac{1}{2}$$ and the equation of our Tangent line is given by $$y=\frac{1}{2}x+1$$

Comment: Alright, I get it now. Thank you for your help

Comment: you are welcome, nice that i could help you!

Comment: sorry, does the tangent have to obey $x>=0$ as the function of the curve?

Comment: yes it must be $$x>0$$ but the Limit $x$ tends to $0^+$ exists